# How to ignore sortDescriptor in NSFetchedResultsController

Tags: iphone, ios, nsfetchedresultscontroller, nssortdescriptor

I'm using `NSFetchedResultsController` to retrieve data for a `UITableView`.
but problem is I have to use `sortDescriptor` with `NSFetchedResultsController`.
I don't want to sort my data, I want to show data in the table as the order I have inserted them in the table.

Is there any way to handle this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks for your answer. I have added another property named sorting number and implement this way:

```
NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
chapterSN = [userDefaults objectForKey:@"sortingNumber"];
if (chapterSN == Nil) {
    NSInteger chapterSortingValue = 0;
    chapterSN = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:chapterSortingValue];
    [userDefaults setValue:chapterSN forKey:@"sortingNumber"];
 }
 else {
     NSInteger chapterSortingValue = [chapterSN integerValue];
     chapterSortingValue = chapterSortingValue+1;
     chapterSN = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:chapterSortingValue];
     [userDefaults setValue:chapterSN forKey:@"sortingNumber"];
 }
```

Answer (score 6):

If you want your data sorted by the order they are inserted then you need a field to record this order.

A nice way to do this is to add a `creationDate` property to your object, then use the `awakeFromInsert` method to automatically record the insertion time.

```
- (void)awakeFromInsert
{
    [super awakeFromInsert];
    [self setValue:[NSDate date] forKey:@"creationDate"];
}
```

Now when you want to sort them by insertion order you are all set.

Comment: An even nicer way is to set the creation date in the context saved notification, so that all the objects inserted in the same save, will all have the same timestamp.